# Why isn't this collision being triggered?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collision

I have this script attached to a game object in unity that when touching another gameobject with the **tag** *"wisdom"*, will trigger this event. there are no error codes, and the **debug.log** isn't working either.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class range : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject big;
    // Start is called before the first frame update


     public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){
            if(col.gameObject.tag == "wisdom"){
                    Debug.Log("yourmother");
                         big.SetActive(true);
             }
     }
     public void OnTriggerExit(Collider col){
                    if(col.gameObject.tag == "wisdom"){
                         big.SetActive(false);
             }

}
}
```

Comment: Is it a 2D game or a 3D game?  If it is a 2D game you will need to use OnTriggerEnter2D and OnTriggerExit2D both of which take a Collider2D parameter.  Other than that make sure your gameobjects meet these requirements: `Both GameObjects must contain a Collider component. One must have Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody. If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both GameObjects do not have a Rigidbody component.`

Comment: Did you set it to trigger or collide?